# How to save/load a tensorflow hub module to/from a custom path?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-hub

The `tensorflow_hub` library maintainers has made it every easy for users to download and use the pre-trained tensorflow modules, e.g.:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1")
```

But from the `sys.stderr` it seemed like it was saving the module locally to a temporary directory, i.e.

> INFO:tensorflow:Using
>   /var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules to
>   cache modules. INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_0:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_0 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_1:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_1 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_10:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_10 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_11:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_11 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_12:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_12 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_13:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_13 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_14:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_14 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_15:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_15 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_16:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_16 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_2:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_2 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_3:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_3 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_4:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_4 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_5:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_5 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_6:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_6 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_7:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_7 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_8:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_8 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Embeddings_en/sharded_9:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Embeddings_en/sharded_9 INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_0/weights:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_0/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_1/weights:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_1/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/weights:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_3/projection:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_3/projection
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_3/weights:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with Encoder_en/DNN/ResidualHidden_3/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_0/bias:0 from
>   checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_0/bias
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_0/weights:0
>   from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_0/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_1/bias:0 from
>   checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_1/bias
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_1/weights:0
>   from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_1/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_2/bias:0 from
>   checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_2/bias
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_2/weights:0
>   from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SHARED_RANK_ANSWER/response_encoder_0/tanh_layer_2/weights
>   INFO:tensorflow:Initialize variable
>   module/SNLI/Classifier/LinearLayer/bias:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SNLI/Classifier/LinearLayer/bias INFO:tensorflow:Initialize
>   variable module/SNLI/Classifier/LinearLayer/weights:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SNLI/Classifier/LinearLayer/weights INFO:tensorflow:Initialize
>   variable module/SNLI/Classifier/tanh_layer_0/bias:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SNLI/Classifier/tanh_layer_0/bias INFO:tensorflow:Initialize
>   variable module/SNLI/Classifier/tanh_layer_0/weights:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with SNLI/Classifier/tanh_layer_0/weights INFO:tensorflow:Initialize
>   variable module/global_step:0 from checkpoint
>   b'/var/folders/j6/xczfl75n3sbfwpg4190gpb104vnlxt/T/tfhub_modules/c6f5954ffa065cdb2f2e604e740e8838bf21a2d3/variables/variables' with global_step

After a machine reboot, the module gets deleted and running the `hub.Module('...')` code again would re-download the module.

**Is is possible to save the module to a custom directory and afterwards load from the custom directory?**

If it's possible, **how to save/load a tensorflow hub module to/from a custom path?**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to specify/use a custom directory :) For instructions, please see the section called "Caching Modules" at https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/basics

Comment: This answer should be more specific with at least one example.

Comment: the link is also broken! :(

Answer (score 21):

You can download your model need from url + '?tf-hub-format=compressed'

i tried downloading elmo and it worked

url = https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2 + '?tf-hub-format=compressed'

eg: https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2?tf-hub-format=compressed

the model will be downloaded as a tarfile to your machine.

once you untar the file, it will have tfhub_module.pb

Comment: How do i use this downloaded model ?

Comment: Sundeep: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60578801/854477

Answer (score 10):

- Take the URL and change it from:

> https://**tfhub.dev**/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1

To:

> https://**storage.googleapis.com/tfhub-modules**/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1.**tar.gz**

- Download using Curl or browser.
- Extract to a prefered location (e.g. ***/home/admin/embed/***)
- Change your code to:

.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub 
embed = hub.load('/home/admin/embed/')
```

Answer (score 6):

1) Find your model: e.g. https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v1/feature_vector/1

2) Get the real download path:

> replace tfhub.dev with storage.googleapis.com/tfhub-modules and append
>   .tar.gz as the suffix.

3) Prepare the cache:

> On some platforms, TF hub will log the cache directory, but some
>   won’t. Specifying the cache location in the code is much more
>   reliable. Just put the following code in your file before calling
>   tfhub to do so.

```
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = '/tmp/tfhub'
```

reference: [How to run TF hub locally without internet connection](https://medium.com/@xianbao.qian/how-to-run-tf-hub-locally-without-internet-connection-4506b850a915)

Answer (score 3):

For those still looking for an answer, specifically for ELMO, as @harikris said, you can use

url = https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2 + '?tf-hub-format=compressed'

format to download a module, e.g. [this link](https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2?tf-hub-format=compressed)

After downloading, extract the contents into a folder and then in the hub.Module code simply replace your URL with the path to the directory, as stated in

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/basics

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't set the `TFHUB_CACHE_DIR` environment variable value, the default cache directory is:

```
cache_dir = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "tfhub_modules")
```

And the downloaded hub is inside it.

Comment: Adding reference to the answer:  https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching