# How to load TF hub model from local system

Tags: python, tensorflow

One way is to download the model each time from `tensorflow_hub` like following

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

hub_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim128/1"
embed = hub.KerasLayer(hub_url)
embeddings = embed(["A long sentence.", "single-word", "http://example.com"])
print(embeddings.shape, embeddings.dtype)
```

I want to download the file once and use again and again with out downloading each time

Answer (score 10):

1. Download your model from url + "?tf-hub-format=compressed"
   e.g. "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim128/1?tf-hub-format=compressed"
2. Untar
3. Load untarred folder in code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.KerasLayer('path/to/untarred/folder')
embeddings = embed(["A long sentence.", "single-word", "http://example.com"])
print(embeddings.shape, embeddings.dtype)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `hub.load()` method to load a TF Hub module. Also, the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/load) say,

> Currently this method is fully supported only with TensorFlow 2.x and
>   with modules created by calling `tensorflow.saved_model.save()`. The
>   method works in both eager and graph modes.

The `hub.load` method has an argument `handle`. The types of modules handles are,

1. Smart URL resolvers such as tfhub.dev, e.g.: `https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1`.
2. A directory on a file system supported by Tensorflow containing module files. This may include a local directory (e.g. `/usr/local/mymodule`) or a Google Cloud Storage bucket (`gs://mymodule`).
3. A URL pointing to a TGZ archive of a module, e.g. `https://example.com/mymodule.tar.gz`.

You can use the 2nd and the 3rd points.

Comment: `hub_module = hub.load('/tmp/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/')` didn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

if anyone is wondering where the model is saved by default on windows, like me, it's here.

> C:\Users\AvrakDavra\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\

Obviously you can download anywhere and mention that path and tfhub will take from there, but in case.
To instantly open the temp forlder on windows.

1. Press WindowsButton+R
2. Write %TEMP%

It'll open the temp folder for your username, and there the tfhub_modules folder be by default. It'll contain folders as below

[image]

Content of the text file are similar to below.

`Module: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4`
`Download Time: 2021-07-17 18:17:09.714147`
`Downloader Hostname: LAPTOP(PID:12720)`

Comment: If you don't want to mention a manual path everytime, but you have manually downloaded the model, you can put it the default location with a specific name. The name of the folder is actually decided by tfhub when it first tries to download it, it creates a .lock file which once download completes becomes a .txt file, and a .tmp folder which once download completes becomes a normal folder. The folder is where all the content of the tar goes, The txt file is to tell if the download was completed or not.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps others may benefit from a concrete, reproducible answer. This post corresponds to this [specific tfhub model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4).

**tensorflow_hub version:  0.12.0**

**tensorflow version:  2.2.0**

I set up the following path on my Linux server:

```sh
# Note, I manually created this entire path before ever downloading tfhub models
/opt/tfhub/tf2/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_4/
```

(For various reasons, we have some needs for Tensorflow 1.x still, so I figured it might be a good idea to separate models based on if they are designed to work with tensorflow 1.x vs tensorflow 2.x, hence the `tf2` in my path)

I then downloaded the model file, pushed it to my Linux server, placed it in the above location, and exectued:

```sh
# bash
tar xzf bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_4.tar.gz
```

That gave me the following files:

```
# python
import os
os.listdir("/opt/tfhub/tf2/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_4/")
>>> ['keras_metadata.pb', 'saved_model.pb', 'assets', 'variables']
```

So then I can load the model like so:

```
# python
import tensorflow_hub as tfhub
import tensorflow as tf
bert_layer = tfhub.KerasLayer(tfhub.load("/opt/tfhub/tf2/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_4"))
```