# How to manage model file, when load more than 2 models downloading mannually from Tensorflow Hub?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-hub

I tried to download model from the url
It showed error: `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>`

and solved this problem with [How to load TF hub model from local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578801/how-to-load-tf-hub-model-from-local-system)

But there are too many model files and all need to be called like `saved_model.pb`
Is any better way to manage these files?

Hope there is a tree or real project structure suggestion.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, TF Hub library (hub.load) automatically downloads models from tfhub.dev into the local TEMP directory. To enable downloading of multiple models, each model is placed into a directory corresponding to that models name (e.g. /tmp/hash()/). You could consider adopting a similar structure in your case.